# Draw path in background with respect to shape

Tags: android, drawing, android-canvas, surfaceview

I'm going through a for loop over elemets of a synchronized ArrayList inside the draw method of a SurfaceView like this:

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
   for(MyObject o : system) {
     canvas.drawPath(o.getPath(), mPaint);
     canvas.drawCircle(o.getX(), o.getY(), radius, mPaint);
   }
}
```

The problem is that this will draw next elements in the list on top of previous elements. There is a way to make the paths drawn behind all circles without proliferation of for loops?

Comment: Are you clearing the Canvas first?  SurfaceViews are double-buffered.

Comment: @fadden Yes, I call canvas.drawColor(color) before the loop, sorry...